# JavaScript click function null value in text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I need to null the value in text box on click, currently I have written a code as such:

```
<div class="keyword_non">
                    <h1>Keywords : <a class="someClass question_off" title="Keywords "></a></h1>
                    <h2><input type="text" name="kw1" value="one" /></h2>
                    <h2><input type="text" name="kw2" value="two" /></h2>
                    <h2><input type="text" name="kw3" value="three" /></h2>
                    <h2><input type="text" name="kw4" value="four" /></h2>
                      
                </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/functions/javascript/custom/non_profit_edit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/functions/javascript/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/functions/javascript/custom/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Inside non_profit_edit.js i have written as such

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                           
        $(".kw1").click(function() { 
        $(".kw1").val(" ");          
        });
        
        $(".kw2").click(function() { 
        $(".kw2").val(" ");          
        });
        
        $(".kw3").click(function() { 
        $(".kw3").val(" ");          
        });
        
        $(".kw4").click(function() { 
        $(".kw4").val(" ");          
        });
        
});
```

But write now its not working properly. Is this any browser issues or error in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the selector the '.' indicates a class.  For names use

```
$('[name="kw1"]'). //
```

Answer (score 1):

Error in code.

Your selector `".kw1"` selects an element with `kw1` as the `class` attribute. None of your inputs have a class, they just have `name`s. Add classes to them or replace the selector in your jQuery to this format: `$('[name="kw1"]')`

You can also simplify your function by doing this:

```
$('.keyword_non')
    .on('click', 'input[type="text"]', function(e) {
        this.value = ''; // input that was clicked on
    }
```

Comment: `$(e.target).val(''); ` is convoluted and will fail in a good number of browsers. Just use `this.value = '';`. Or if you really must use jQuery, then `$(this).val('');`, but it seems like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Comment: Edited. Not sure which browsers that would fail in though.

Comment: It will fail in any browser that doesn't support event.target (such as IE 8 and lower and those using the same event model).

Answer (score 0):

This is a syntax error in your code.you does not use dot(.) in click function.Dot(.) will use for class. when kw1 is name in your input